# Calculating leap years between two pre determined years

Tags: ruby, output

As in the title, I require help understanding an issue regarding the calculation of leap years between two starting years, when the program is executed from the command line, I always receive the same output regardless of input.

My code is as follows:

```
while true
puts 'Input starting year:'
year_1 = gets.chomp
num_year_1 = year_1.to_i
puts 'Input second year:'
year_2 = gets.chomp
num_year_2 = year_1.to_i

puts 'These are the leap years between these two years:'

    if num_year_1 > num_year_2
        while num_year_1 >= num_year_2
            if num_year_1 % 4 == 0 && num_year_1 % 100 == 0
                puts num_year_1 
            end
            num_year_1 -= num_year_1 - 1
        end
    elsif num_year_2 > num_year_1
         while num_year_2 >= num_year_1
            if num_year_2 % 4 == 0 && num_year_2 % 100 == 0
                puts num_year_2 
            end
            num_year_2 -= 1
        end
    elsif num_year_1 == num_year_2
        puts 'These 2 years are the same, please try again.'
    end

if year_1 == 'end'
    break
end
end
```

And I always receive this as the output:

```
These are the leap years between these 2 years:
These 2 years are the same, try again
```

The only input that affects this is the 'end' command, which replies with the same output but does complete the break in the loop.

I do not understand why this is happening, because in my mind, my program has correct ruby grammar, and so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if num_year_1 % 4 == 0 && num_year_1 % 100 == 0` is not the way to find leap years.

Answer (score 3):

Your existing code:

```
puts 'Input starting year:'
year_1 = gets.chomp
num_year_1 = year_1.to_i
puts 'Input second year:'
year_2 = gets.chomp
num_year_2 = year_1.to_i
```

Should instead be:

```
puts 'Input starting year:'
year_1 = gets.chomp
num_year_1 = year_1.to_i
puts 'Input second year:'
year_2 = gets.chomp
num_year_2 = year_2.to_i
```

The issue is that you are assigning both `num_year_1` and `num_year_2` to `year_1.to_i`, when the latter should be assigned to `year_2.to_i`

Answer (score 2):

Far easier and implementing the correct algorithm for calculating leap years:

```
def isLeapYear(yearVar)
  ((yearVar % 4 == 0 && !(yearVar % 100 == 0)) || (yearVar % 400 == 0))
end

while true
  puts 'Input starting year:'
  num_year_1 = gets.to_i
  puts 'Input second year:'
  num_year_2 = gets.to_i
  if num_year_1 < num_year_2
    puts 'These are the leap years between these two years:'
    for i in num_year_1..num_year_2
      puts i if isLeapYear(i)
    end
  elsif num_year_1 == num_year_2
    puts 'These two years are the same.  Try again...'
  else
    puts 'Starting year must be less than second year.  Try again...'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 7th line of code, `num_year_2 = year_1.to_i` has a typo: I'm sure you meant to put `num_year_2 = year_2.to_i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise one.

```
(start_year..end_year).each do |year|
  next if year % 4   != 0
  next if year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0
  puts year
end
```